# Why are my array items not passing into my function on foreach PHP for GraphQL?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, graphql

My items from my array seem to not be passed into the my ***'resolve' => function***. Right now the function returns ***fail***.  If I replace $meta with an array item then it works. Im trying to fetch meta values for GraphQL and dont want to make a function per field.

```
            add_action( 'graphql_register_types', function() {
                $metas = array('phone', 'city', 'state', 'zip');
                foreach($metas as $meta){
                    register_graphql_field( 'Location', $meta, [
                        'type' => 'String',
                        'description' => __( 'The post data', 'wp-graphql' ),
                        'resolve' => function($post, $meta) {
                        $GQL_data = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), $meta, true);
                        return ! empty( $GQL_data  ) ? $GQL_data  : 'fail';
                        }
                    ] );
                }
            });
```

**Expected GraphQL output:**

"phone": "123-123-1234",

"city": "Los Angeles",

"state": "CA",

"zip": "99922"

**currently all items have a value of:** "fail"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your resolve function when trying to pass a variable into the scope of an anonymous function use the `use` keyword. What you doing in you code is just renaming the the second parameter (which is the `arguments` array, and in this case its empty) to `$meta` and passing that to the `get_post_meta` function array.

Try refactoring your code to this.

```
add_action( 'graphql_register_types', function() {

   $metas = array('phone', 'city', 'state', 'zip');

   foreach( $metas as $meta ) {

       register_graphql_field( 'Location', $meta, [
           'type'        => 'String',
           'description' => __( 'The post data', 'wp-graphql' ),
           'resolve'     => function( $post ) use( $meta ) { // Note use( $meta )
               $GQL_data = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), $meta, true);
               return ! empty( $GQL_data  ) ? $GQL_data  : 'fail';
           }
       ] );

   }
} );
```